# Missing assembly reference error shows, but the references are already exists

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nuget

The issue I am facing is there is a Web API project in VS 2012, I try to implement JWT in that project. We have a coding concept that, if any NuGet packages are used our project that must be moved into 'ExternalDLLs' folder in the project, and refer the DLL's from this folder. This is to avoid unwanted NuGet updates. Please see the installed NuGet packages below.

- Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging -Version 5.2.4
- Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens -Version 5.1.5
- Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 5.1.5

All references are correctly done from the 'ExternalDLL' folder But it shows an error like below image.

[image]

There is a blue line in the 'IdentityModel' text and it shows a message 
**are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**. **I already referred the DLL's from ExternalDLLs folder**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those references dll's into your project. (Because you removed them).

1. Right Click the Project
2. Add Reference..
3. Click Browse vertical Tab
4. Click on the bottom "Browse..." button and navigate into your ExternalDlls folder.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable reply. It's already done. But I there any reason to occur the compatibility issue of NuGet packages?